# xcode 4 applescript radio button if statements

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, applescript

I have app created (Cocoa-AppleScript Application) that executed a shell command using the value of a user-supplied text field and an "install" button. I would like to grow the application to incorporate radio buttons (list) that allow a user to select one or more radio buttons and upon clicking the install button, the correlating command to each radio button will execute. I havent been able to find much info online related to radio buttons and if statements.

I did find this article but it doesnt appear to work with xcode 4:
http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24755

```
  on InstallButton_(sender)
    set hostName to ""
    set hostName to textField's stringValue as string
    do shell script ("/usr/sbin/scutil --set HostName " & hostName) with administrator privileges
    do shell script ("/usr/sbin/scutil --set ComputerName " & hostName) with administrator privileges
   #IF RADIO BUTTON 1 IS SELECTED
         RUN COMMAND1
   #IF RADIO BUTTON 2 IS SELECTED
         RUN COMMAND2
end InstallButton_
```

Comment: Ive performed extensive searches on the above request but am finding limited material relating to the issue at hand.

Comment: I found the following article but it doesnt appear to be compatible with xcode 4. <http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24755>

Comment: I wasnt able to find a solution using a radio button (list) but I was able to find out how to get the exact result using checkboxes.


            property checkBox : missing value
            set checkBoxValue to ""
        set checkBoxValue to checkBox's integerValue as string
        #display dialog checkBoxValue
        if checkBoxValue = 1
            #run policy
        end

if the checkbox is checked the checkBoxValue parameter = 1 if it is not checked the value is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasnt able to find a solution using a radio button (list) but I was able to find out how to get the exact result using checkboxes. property checkBox :

```
missing value set checkBoxValue to "" 
set checkBoxValue to checkBox's integerValue as string 
#display dialog checkBoxValue 
if checkBoxValue = 1 
#run policy 
end
```

if the checkbox is checked the checkBoxValue parameter = 1 if it is not checked the value is 0.